# Sybase ASE Auditing on sp_addlogin sp_droplogin sp_modifylogin

Tags: audit, sybase-ase-15.7

We have requirement to enable auditing on Sybase ASE(Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 27351 SMP SP139 /P/ia64/HP-UX B.11.31/ase157sp138x/4041/64-bit/FBO/Tue Aug  8 07:33:11 2017) and I enabled the same on master database as below:

[image: Result of sp_displayaudit]

I was under impression that this would also enable auditing on any change in login/user(sp_addlogin, sp_modifylogin, sp_droplogin, sp_adduser, sp_dropuser) as create/drop/alter was handled at master level, but that was incorrect as this is applicable to only objects and not users/logins. Recently when I dropped one user, it was not logged in the audit event; after checking multiple documents on the Sybase documentation and different portals on the internet and also with the help of vendor, came to know that one more type of auditing(login_admin) needs to be enabled in order to capture these events in audit events.

I executed below command and was expecting that this would solve the underlying issue:

```
1> sp_audit "login_admin", "all", "all", "on"
2> go
Audit option has been changed and has taken effect immediately.
(return status = 0)
1> sp_displayaudit "login"
2> go
No logins currently have auditing enabled.
(return status = 0)
1>
```

As evident from the result of sp_displayaudit, logins are still not being audited. I am not really sure if this requires ASE reboot to take effect or I am missing something here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying hard on this without finding any workable solution, raised a case with Sybase support and they have provided solution.

Below are the commands that can be used to satisfy the mentioned requirement:

```
--Audit any change at procedure level for login/user/alias

use sybsystemprocs 
go 
sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_addlogin", "on" 
go 
sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_droplogin", "on" 
go 
sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_modifylogin", "on" 
go 
sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_adduser", "on" 
go 
sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_dropuser", "on" 
go

sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_addalias", "on" 
go

sp_audit "exec_procedure", "all", "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_dropalias", "on" 
go


--Audit any change at table level for login/user/alias 

sp_audit "delete", "all", "master.dbo.syslogins", "on"
go
sp_audit "insert", "all", "master.dbo.syslogins", "on"
go
sp_audit "update", "all", "master.dbo.syslogins", "on"
go

sp_audit "delete", "all", "master.dbo.sysusers", "on"
go
sp_audit "insert", "all", "master.dbo.sysusers", "on"
go
sp_audit "update", "all", "master.dbo.sysusers", "on"
go

sp_audit "delete", "all", "master.dbo.sysalternates", "on"
go
sp_audit "insert", "all", "master.dbo.sysalternates", "on"
go
sp_audit "update", "all", "master.dbo.sysalternates", "on"
go


sp_audit "delete", "all", "master.dbo.syssrvroles", "on"
go
sp_audit "insert", "all", "master.dbo.syssrvroles", "on"
go
sp_audit "update", "all", "master.dbo.syssrvroles", "on"
go


sp_audit "delete", "all", "master.dbo.sysloginroles", "on"
go
sp_audit "insert", "all", "master.dbo.sysloginroles", "on"
go
sp_audit "update", "all", "master.dbo.sysloginroles", "on"
go
```

I am sure this would help to anyone who wants to enable auditing at Sybase ASE level and is not sure how to achieve the same.